# Test for participant subgroups in gradual means shift

Tags: mean, group-differences, fuzzy

In an experiment with 44 participants I have measured the response time for a set of stimuli, where the response could be *a* or *b*. The means of the two responses do not differ significantly (783.3 vs 785.4 ms).

However, for individual participants the means are different: for 10 participants the mean for *a* is more than 50ms lower than the mean for *b* (<100ms for 3 of those 10), for 16 participants the mean for *a* is >50ms higher than the mean for *b* (8 participants >100ms).

Therefore I think that there might be three different subgroups: those with a preference for *a*, a preference for *b* and no preference, with a gradual shift between the groups. The equal means overall is in this scenario just a coincidence. How do I test this?

One possibility is 44 separate t-tests (one for each participant), of which some of them will show a significant difference in means and others will not. How can I interpret such a result? A test on the full dataset would be preferred however. An univariate ANOVA with participant as factor could be used, but I'm not sure if that is appropriate for this hypothesis. Any thoughts?